# Modifiabilité OU Modificabilité?

Tags: choix-de-mot, terminologie

En anglais, il existe le terme ***modifiability*** : la capacité de quelque-chose à être modifié.

En français, on peut trouver parfois ces 2 termes proches:

- ***Modificabilité*** - proposé par le correcteur de *Word* quand on tape "*modifiabilité*". Proposé également par [Littre.org](http://www.littre.org/definition/modificabilit%C3%A9) et [Cnrtl.fr](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/modificabilit%C3%A9)
- ***Modifiabilité*** - proposé par le correcteur de *Google* quand on tape "*modificabilité*". Présent aussi sur [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/modifiabilit%C3%A9).

Les 2 termes sont utilisés de manière plus ou moins égale selon les résultats de recherche sur Google:

- ***Modifiabilité***: 3 450 résultats
- ***Modificabilité***: 2 910 résultats

Alors, lequel est correct?

Comment: I had a hard time finding definitions on the English term. I did find one in the Merriam Webster but it was very short and it was only in their specialized and unabridged section... I couldn't find other synonyms in the thesaurus either. I am not surprised that finding a French equivalent is difficult. May I suggest finding another way to express this in English? You may find a more natural term in French. You may start with [alterability... A word that has been around since 1790](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alterability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aucun de ces deux termes ne semble être accepté par les ouvrages de référence générale. Ce qui veut dire que la langue courante ne contient vraisemblablement pas un seul terme pour exprimer cette idée. On dira plutôt que quelque chose a *un caractère, une nature modifiable*. Si l'on veut, on peut s'aventurer dans les synonymes et penser à *flexibilité*, *souplesse*, *variabilité*.

Cependant, l'anglais *modifiability* ne semble pas être un terme souvent employé en langue courante. Il semble être plutôt employé dans la langue informatique. Or, dans ce vaste domaine, [Termium, la base de données terminologiques du gouvernement du Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=MODIFIABILITY), regroupe trois sources appuyant le terme français *modifiabilité* :

> **Domaine** : Vocabulaire des technologies de l'information, fiche du 30 janvier 2006
>
> Information technology: vocabulary. Part 07. Computer programming = Technologie de l'information : vocabulaire. Partie 07. Programmation des ordinateurs.
>
> International Organization for Standardization.
>
> Genève : ISO, 2000.
>
> **Domaine** : Programmes et programmation (Informatique), fiche du 26 octobre 1995
>
> Information technology: vocabulary. Part 7. Computer programming.
>
> International Organization for Standardization.
>
> Paris : ISO : AFNOR, 1994.
>
> **Domaine** : Intelligence artificielle, fiche du 6 décembre 1989
>
> Intelligence logicielle : dictionnaire français-anglais
>
> Pavel, Silvia.
>
> Ottawa : Secrétariat d'État du Canada, 1989.

Selon ces sources, du moins en informatique, *modifiabilité* est le terme normalisé qui est l'équivalent de *modificability*.

Comment: Oui, "modifiability" est souvent utilisé en architecture logicielle (http://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=8299)

Answer (score 6):

Le [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modifiabilit%C3%A9,modificabilit%C3%A9&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1;,modifiabilit%C3%A9;,c0;.t1;,modificabilit%C3%A9;,c0) semble indiquer que *modificabilité* était largement plus utilisé jusque dans les années 50, mais que les deux semblent être utilisés depuis. Je ne sais pas cependant à quel point on peut faire confiance à des résultats tirés de Ngram pour ce cas.

Personnellement, j'aurais plus tendance à utiliser *modifiabilité*, ne serait-ce que pour le rapprocher de l'adjectif *modifiable*.

Answer (score 1):

Une petite recherche sur google indique que les seuls dictionnaires à se ranger du coté de *modifiabilité* sont Wiktionary et TheFreeDictionary.

De son coté, *modificabilité* renvoie dés sa première page de nombreux dictionnaires reconnus, dont ceux que vous avez cités. On ne trouve trace d'aucun des deux mots dans le [dictionnaire de l'Académie Française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/generic/showp.exe?121;s=1437208560;p=main.txt), cependant.

Le graphique fourni par Alexis Pigeon semble suggérer que *modifiabilité* serait un emprunt récent à l'anglais. Je dois reconnaître que ce choix sonne mieux à mon oreille. Cependant, votre question mentionne que vous recherchez le mot correct (et pas seulement le plus utilisé), auquel cas il me paraît clair que tout pointe vers *modificabilité*.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: modifiabilité.

Version longue:

Je serais très surpris que *modificabilité* soit un mot qui existe en français.

En français, pour exprimer la possibilité, on utilise le suffixe *-abilité* du latin *-abilitas*; lui-même composé des suffixes latins *-abilis* (français: *-able*) et *-tas* (français: *-té* ou sa variante *-ité*).  Dans le cas de *-abilité*, le *-ité* modifie le suffixe *-able* en *-abilité*

À ma connaissance, *-cabilité* n'est pas un suffixe existant, et *modificable* n'existe pas en français.  Le seul *modificable* que je vois, c'est une variante obsolète de *modifiable*, en anglais.  En français, nous utilisons *modifiable*.

Donc, le mot à utiliser en français serait ***modifiabilité***

D'ailleurs, même en anglais, des recherches pour *modifiability* renvoient des résultats, alors que *modificability* nous suggère plutôt *modifiability*, quoique le précédent serait théoriquement bon, cependant obsolète.

Answer (score 1):

Il existe une version négative du concept: "immuabilité".

Pour ce que ca vaut, google donne 52,500 réponses.

Par contre, "muabilité" n'existe pas vraiment avec 3000 réponses.

En informatique, on utilise les mot "mutable" et "immutable"

Comment: on dit aussi parfois "non mutable".